# Using .not function with .hover in jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm trying to use the following block of code, but is not working. I need to use the hover function, but do not want to show the style `display: none` if the div has a class myclass:

```
jQuery('.image').not('.myclass').hover( function()
{
     jQuery(this).find('.arrow').show();
}, function()
{
     jQuery(this).find('.arrow').hide();
});
```

Comment: Please define "not working."  HTML would help, too.

Comment: So that is saying that you monitor elements with the `image` class that do not have the `myclass` class. So `<div class="image"/>` would be matched, but `<div class="image myclass"/>` would not. Is that correct? I suspect you might be matching classes on the wrong elements.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `not`, you might consider an `if statement`.  Something like

```
$('.image').mouseenter(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('myclass')){
        $('.arrow').show();
    }    
});

$('.image').mouseleave(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('myclass')){
        $('.arrow').hide();
    }    
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ccB7K/2/

Comment: +1 I agree with Jason here. I am guessing that `.myclass` is being added sometime after these statements are executed. Then the show example would not work were Jason's will.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .not, use JQuery's not CSS style selector instead.

Implementation here. http://jsfiddle.net/CJp4A/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
jQuery('.image:not(.myclass)')
```

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: That should have the same effect as use `.not()` though, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: You are right although as tangent comment on the choice, the selector version tends to be faster (sometimes upwards of 60% when compared to .not()) depending on the browser.  [link](http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not)

Comment: I wouldn't use `.not()` unless I was chaining a bunch of stuff and wanted to `.end()` it or similar. But the speed issue has nothing to do with it not working.

Comment: Aye, hence the mention of **tangent** on my comment :)